# AWS terminating instance instead of stopping it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to recover the AWS Key pair file since it was lost. I am following the steps to replace the one I lost that aws have on their page (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair) but I need to stop the instance and when I tried stopping the instance it terminated it and created a new one. I believe this the behavior is because of the auto scaling group but I am not sure since I am a AWS newbie. So, my problem is that I need a new key pair file without deleting the current instance.

Comment: is your instance in autoscaling group ? then go to autoscaling console and set your instance to `Stand By`. After this if you stop the instance, the ASG will not terminate the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can de-attach the instance from the autoscaling and the key recovery.
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/detach-instance-asg.html

(or)

If the instance is in an autoscaling group, you need to create a new launch configuration by copying the existing one, change the key pair and then edit the autoscaling group to use the new launch configuration.

Here are the exact steps.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/change-launch-config.html